# Returning data to client following AJAX post request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send a POST request from my chrome extension to my node.js server, and then have the server send back a JS file to my extension. What is the best way of doing this?

Currently tried this:

Server.js

```
function sendJSfile(req, res) {
    var body = req.body.apples
    console.log(body)

    if (body.length >= 3) {
        console.log("Long!")
    } else{
        console.log("Short!")
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
        fs.createReadStream("./manual.js").pipe(res);
    }
}
```

Client.js

```
     request("https://61d6b1ac.ngrok.io/api/panels/hitme", "post", "JSON", {apples})
    .done(function(res){
      console.log(res)

    })
  })

 function request(url, method, dataType, data){
  return $.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: method,
  dataType: dataType,
  data: data
   })
  }
```

Comment: Updated my question with my current server side code! Post request works fine, just doesn't send the manual.js back to the client?

Comment: Have you added the server url in ["permissions"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) key of the extension's manifest.json? Do you make that POST request in a popup/background script of the extension or a content script?

Comment: The ajax is from the content script. I've tested a GET request(without sending data to the server) and the manual.js executes fine. Manifest is all fine as well. Does the code look like it should work? I've not used AJAX a lot

Comment: ^ I've updated question with content script code.

Comment: I think you should make the POST request from  the background script of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can notice is that you have written your AJAX to receive JSON data from server but sending content-type as javascript from server which might not work.

Also as per your question, you want to send the js file back to the client. There are 3 ways to do this-

1. You can send the content of the JS file as a string and then execute in your ajax success response. This is bad way to do this.
2. You can send the public url of JS file from your NodeJS server and then using `<script>` tag you can download the same in JS.
3. You can also use `$.getScript` if you know the public JS url from your client.

As far as your above server code is concerned, you can return the JS content from server as follows -

```
    function sendJSfile(req, res) {
    var body = req.body.apples
    console.log(body)

    if (body.length >= 3) {
    console.log("Long!")
    // here you will need to send error or something to the request
     res.send();
    } else{
    console.log("Short!")
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
    //fs.createReadStream("./manual.js").pipe(res);
    // if you want to send manual.js content, then this can be sent as  following
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream("./manual.js");

     readStream.on('open', function () {
     // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
          readStream.pipe(res);
     });

    // This catches any errors that happen while creating the readable stream 
       readStream.on('error', function(err) {
    res.end(err);
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the code under point 3. on my server and removed the JSON datatype from my client code, now however it IS executing manual.js correctly, but also console.logging the entire manual.js?

Comment: I've just used your code above, which seems to have worked. My last problem is that now its erroring, as '.length' is undefined? Presumably because its no longer JSON?

Comment: Content is normal javascript!

Comment: is it JSON data or javascript which needs to be executed on client ?

Comment: Its the javascript that needs to be executed by the client. Just testing it again, it only fails to execute the javascript when I set the POST request data type as JSON. Are you aware of any work arounds? I have to be able to measure the '.length' of the req.body

Comment: Also, when the POST request doesn't have son specified as the data type, it just console.logs 'undefined'